# Is alternate key indicated while creating a table but this alternate key isn't posted from any other table

Tags: sql

The question is that if I have relation R(A,B,C,D) where A is PK and C if Alternate key for that relation, would I, while creating table based on that relation, need to indicate that C is an unique key? What I mean is:

```
create table R (
                 A A's domain,
                 B B's domain,
                 C C's domain,
                 D D's domain,
                 primary key A,
                 unique C 
                )
```

Do I have to specify that C is an unique key for that table even though this key isn't posted from any other table (it is just a canditate key which hasn't been selected to be a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

**Unique Key**  is  a constraint, which  means if you declare C as unique , then no duplicates values will be allowed for that column. If you do not specify it , it can have duplicate values, thus failed as a candidate key

Comment: Hi Joe, I do understand what unique key is. The question I'm asking is, if you have multiple candidate keys for a table, i.e. Person(ID,NationalInsuranceNumber,SomeOtherIdentifyingAttribute), so as you see there are three candidate keys, any one of them can be a primary key, but the question I ask is: If you select ID to be pk, would you declare those other two keys in a table as an unique keys?

Comment: If you want to specify that the other column is a candidate key, then its better to specify as a unique key, other wise not required..

Answer (score 0):

If specifying it will prevent *incorrect* data from being inserted into the table (such that there are two rows with the same value in `C`), then the only reason not to do so is if it has proven to be a performance issue, and if you've demonstrated that incorrect data is prevented through some other mechanism.